# How Generating URLs from a template correctly in Symfony2/Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I'm working with Symfony2 and:

I have this in the routing.yml

```
_welcome:
    resource: "@AcmeBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
```

I this method within a controller:

```
/**
 * @Route("/{page}")
 */
public function staticAction($page)
{
    return $this->render('AcmeBundle:Static:'.$page.'.html.twig');
}
```

To generate common pages:

```
/home
/contact 
/privacy
```

But when I make the url on the menu:

```
<a href="{{ path('_welcome', {'page': 'home'}) }}">Home</a>
<a href="{{ path('_welcome', {'page': 'contact'}) }}">Contact</a>
<a href="{{ path('_welcome', {'page': 'privacy'}) }}">Privacy</a>
```

And I Symfony generates these urls:

```
…./?page=home
…./?page=contact
…./?page=privacy
```

And the right would be:

```
/home
/contact
/privacy
```

What must I do?

Answer (score 55, accepted):

You've to add a route name in your controller route annotations as follow,

```
/**
 * @Route("/{page}", name="static")
 */
public function staticAction($page)
{
    // ... 
}
```

You could then call the twig `path` helper using that name,

```
<a href="{{ path('static', {'page': 'home'}) }}">Home</a>
```

Comment: If you want to keep website url (For instance when you generate it for email), you can use 'url' `<a href="{{ url('static', {'page': 'home'}) }}">Home</a>`