# Updating a twig var inside a function

Tags: javascript, twig

I'm trying to work with twig and javascript. I'm just trying to define a var and update the value inside a click function. Unfortunatelly, the var seems to be updated, but the new value is not updated when the scope of the function ends, so the console log writes 1 the first time and 2 each time I enter in the click function.
Which is the  better way to do this??  Thanks in advance

```
        {% set actual_index = 0 %}
        {% set num_elements = 3 %}

        addNewEvents();
        {% set actual_index = actual_index + 1 %}
        console.log({{ actual_index }})

        $("#load").click(function () { 
            addNewEvents();
            {% set actual_index = actual_index + 1 %}
            console.log({{ actual_index }})
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How to do it cleanly? Separate twig from your javascript. They were not intended to be used together (even though it can work).

You have multiple different ways to retrieve the information for your js. Either use twig and store the information in a hidden input, or get the information with an AJAX call.

for example:

```
var actual_index = -1;
var num_elements = 0;

$.getJSON('ur_here', function(data){
  actual_index = data.actual_index;
  num_elements = data.num_elements;
});
```

But it seems to go further than that, you understand that twig generates HTML server side and sends it to the client? **This happens only once.**

That means your variable you ***set*** only exists server side right? That means that when you do `{{ actual_index }}` it just generates a number client side and not a variable.

```
    {% set actual_index = 0 %}
    {% set num_elements = 3 %}
```

The two above variables exist server side right before twig generates your HTML and sends it to client.

Here is what your js should look like without twig:

```
var actual_index = 0;
var num_elements = 3;

addNewEvents();
actual_index = actual_index + 1;
console.log(actual_index)

$("#load").click(function () { 
    addNewEvents();
    actual_index = actual_index + 1;
    console.log(actual_index);
});
```

---

**EDIT:**

Answering your comment.

```
"{{ asset( path('event_values', { 'programmerid': programmerid, 'actual_index': actual_index, 'num_elements':num_elements } ))|raw }}
```

If the above generates an URL then you're on the right path (otherwise check this post [How Generating URLs from a template correctly in Symfony2/Twig](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15857358/how-generating-urls-from-a-template-correctly-in-symfony2-twig) ).

Now, the first parameter of the getJSON is an URL, and the second parameter is the callback.

Remember that your {{ asset... }} should generate an URL that can be called on the client side.

So after your twig generates your HTML the URL should look something like this:

```
$.getJSON('http//:localhost/path/to/your/ajaxHandler.php', function(data){
  //this is called when you return data from your ajaxHandler.php
  //do something with data
});
```

This way, when you click `ajaxHanlder.php` is called and you can send back the information back in `json` ( `echo json_encode(You array here);` )

Comment: Ok, I understand. I started using twig and javascript because I didn't know how to pass the javascript vars to the controller.

$.getJSON("{{ asset( path('event_values', { 'programmerid': programmerid, 'actual_index':  actual_index, 'num_elements':num_elements } ))|raw }}", null, function(myjson)

reading your answer, maybe a good option should be save the values generated by javascript in a hidden html field and retrieve from this? Or there is another best practice?

Comment: @Joan and to complete my update in the answer. Yes, putting it in a hidden input would probably be the easiest.