# Using the correct href path in a Twig template

Tags: php, url, twig

I have this link in my Twig template:

`<li><a href="categories/{{ category.id }}">{{ category.category }}</a></li>`

On the first page load, it loads as expected.  For example:

`<li><a href="categories/10">Music</a></li>`

When I click on this link, it keep adding this to the url.  For example, if I clicked on it 3 times, I get:

`http://localhost:8080/myApp/categories/categories/categories/10`

How can I get the correct path instead of just keeping adding to it?  Is this a Twig parameter I should be using?

Comment: May be this help you:-http://stackoverflow.com/a/15857401/4248328

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it's because you have given relative URI instead of absolute one.

try giving your base URI before categories

```
<li><a href="{{ YOUR_BASE_URI }}/categories/{{ category.id }}"
```